# MySQL - How can this query be optimised?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

The following query works, but its very slow for 10 records (2 seconds). The profiling says its creating a tmp table, but I'm not sure why.

Basically, I'm joining the current user, to the acl groups, to get all groups they are in, then joining the groups to the companies, to get all companies they are in, then joining the companies to the orders, to get all the orders..

If I remove this line

```
ORDER BY orders.created_on DESC
```

then the query executes in 0.06 secs (more then acceptable)..

Help, any ideas on how to optimize? Many thanks :)

```
SELECT
    orders.uuid,
    companies.name as company_name
FROM
    users u
JOIN    
    users_acl_groups g on   u.uuid = g.user_uuid
JOIN
    users_acl acl on (acl.user_uuid = u.uuid or acl.group_uuid = g.group_uuid) 
JOIN 
    companies on acl.item_uuid = companies.uuid
JOIN
    orders on companies.uuid = orders.company_uuid
WHERE
    u.uuid = 'DDEC8073-5056-C000-01ED583A51CBCA32' and orders.status <> ''
ORDER BY orders.created_on DESC 

limit 0, 10;
```

UPDATE, the explain of the query..

> 1 SIMPLE  orders  ALL                 9403    Using
> temporary; Using filesort
>
> 1 SIMPLE  acl ALL                 1859    Using where;
> Using join buffer
>
> 1 SIMPLE  g   ALL                 2005    Using where;
> Using join buffer
>
> 1 SIMPLE  companies   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 52  table.orders.company_uuid   1
>
> 1 SIMPLE  u   ALL                 33595   Using where;
> Distinct; Using join buffer

Comment: Modified your title, as guessing that it cost you a downvote due to its imperative and demanding tone when your question is worded nicely.

Comment: Try using same query with join applied on any column other than UID. Try doing it with int, float, string, UID and notice the time. Let us also know if you find any variation.

Comment: Do you have an index on orders.created_on ? Show the output on `EXPLAIN` on your query. Maybe you could benefit from other indexes. Which `EXPLAIN` will tell us.

Comment: Yes, `EXPLAIN` would help.
It looks like, without the  `ORDER BY`, the query works from the user, with small joins up to the orders; and in the reverse direction with the `ORDER BY`, from a large cartesian join between orders, companies, acl (maybe the contents of the tmp table) before finally joining with a filtered users...

Comment: Is `users.uuid` indexed? (maybe a unique index) It's strange that the query is not trying to reduce the fatter table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered making a *fact table* style design, as a denormalization step?

Basically it's a kind of many-to-many intersection table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE user_order_fact (
  user_uuid ...
  order_uuid ...
  order_created_on ...
  order_status ...
  company_name ...,
  primary key (user_uuid, order_uuid),
  key (user_uuid, order_status, order_created_on, order_uuid, company_name)
);

... fill with data ...

SELECT
    order_uuid,
    company_name
FROM
    user_order_fact
WHERE
    user_uuid = 'DDEC8073-5056-C000-01ED583A51CBCA32' and order_status <> ''
ORDER BY order_created_on DESC 

limit 0, 10;
```

I'm guessing on the compound index.  You'll have to experiment until you get it right.  Basically you're trying to get the optimizer plan to report that it's **Using index**.

Of course this is storing data redundantly and in denormalized form, so you need to set up some triggers to keep this in sync with the normalized tables.

Comment: Hmm maybe the PK is just order_uuid.  I'm not guaranteeing this is the best design, just trying to give you a feel of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

make sure "orders.created_on" has an index... If it does, then Bill's approach at the top will be the best however will require a bit of work.

Comment: I think it does?    KEY `created_on` (`created_on`)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without knowing much about the existing indexes, or the volume of each tables.

Besides, without much information about the model... does the query return all the results?

Do all users belong to a group? It seems that not... and the query won't return users outside of a group.

Can a group belong to a group, calling for a recursive query?

Comment: I was trying to work that recursive query thing out but I wasn't having much luck :( the table is quiet small, 10,000 records all up. There are no indexes at the moment..

Comment: @Brett: Indexes if present in this case will not work, as NOT operator and Like Operator don't uses Indexes

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what might be the exact reason for it to take 2 sec. Which is not possible for this query fetching 10 records but what is see here are

1. `acl.user_uuid = u.uuid or acl.group_uuid = g.group_uuid`

   UID based join, may be you are also
   using it as a primary key as
   answered above.
2. `ORDER BY orders.created_on`. Using `Order by` on `date` would not be as optimal than using PK or any integer value
   is more appropriate.
3. `orders.status <> ''` If using any indexes on tables then no index
   can be used in this query because
   NOT Operator and Like
   Operator does not uses indexes when used in any query.
4. Volume of records present in a table might be another reason but only due to above factors. Otherwise it could have handled large volume as well.

Major Contributing factor that I think is **UID being used in Joins**
So all the three avoiding conditions can be seen in your query that might make your query lazy

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses.. What does minimized in no.2 mean?

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas:

You actually not selecting `orders.created_on` in Your query. So there is no point of sorting on that column. Maybe, selecting it (`SELECT orders.created_on` ...) would help performance (Just wild guess -- I have no idea what I am talking here).

You can always sort in Your application -- if there is not enormous amount of records returned by Your query.

Sometimes it is more performance wise to use N small queries instead of 1 big sql query. Pseudo code:

```
user_id = get_one("SELECT uuid FROM users WHERE ...");
group_ids = get_many("SELECT uuid FROM groups WHERE user_uuid = " + user_id);
comps_ids = get_many("SELECT DISTINCT item_uuid FROM acls WHERE user_uuid = " + user_id + " OR group_uuid IN " + groups_ids.to_q());
orders = get_many("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE company_uuid IN " + comps_ids.as_q() + " WHERE status <> '' ORDER BY created_on");
```